# Programmatically set metadata for simplesamlphp

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I'm using SimpleSAMLphp for single sign on purposes. The default set up has an authsources.php file that holds the $config data and then a bunch of files in the metadata directory that set the $metadata for each of the IdP's. I don't want this information to be kept in static files. I'd prefer to set the $config and $metadata programmatically.

I've figured out how to do the $config. That's fairly simple. Just create the $config array that you want to use and then pass it to SimpleSAML_Configuration in the constructor. Bada-bing. Bada-boom. Done.

I can't find anything that allows you to manually set the $metadata though. Does SimpleSAMLphp have such a utility that I'm missing?  Basically, I want something that would work like this...

```
$metadata = array(/* some data here */);
$util = new SomeMetaDataObject();
$util->setMetaData($metadata);

// Then do the whole Auth thing after this.
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking at it, it wasn't possible, since all config was statically loaded from files, and impossible to override programmatically. Not sure if that changed by some newer version. But that was the reason why I started writing [light saml php library](https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML) and [saml sp symfony bundle](https://github.com/lightSAML/SpBundle) - a more configurable and reusable SAML library in PHP. Please try it, would appreciate some feedback and means to improve it.